# Compile and run Mixxx in Windows

Tags: c++, qt

I am trying to install [Mixxx](https://www.mixxx.org/) on Windows because I need to customize the software.

Can anyone please help me with the requirements and steps of how to install and compile Mixxx on Windows? When I run it the command prompt goes into an infinite loop which runs for more than 11 hours and results in a system crash.

I have tried the process given in https://www.mixxx.org/wiki/doku.php/compiling_on_windows